# Elasticsearch ICU plugin - Analyzer not found

Tags: maven, plugins, elasticsearch, icu

I'm trying to use the ICU Plugin on an embedded instance of Elasticsearch. I have installed it by adding the dependency to the pom, and set up the settings for the plugin, which seems to be correctly loaded:

```
INFO  -  [Quasar] loaded [analysis-icu], sites []
```

The settings are the following:

```
"index-name": {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ducet_sort": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [ "icu_collation" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The bit of the mapping where I'm trying to use the plugin at looks like this:

```
"primaryName": {
    "type": "string",
        "fields": {
            "sort": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "ducet_sort"
            }
        }
},
```

When I try to `PUT` the mapping file into the index, I get the following exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Analyzer [ducet_sort] not found for field [sort]
```

Does anybody know what's happening here? I did some previous investigation on this and it worked on a standalone instance installed on my machine...

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I'm using ES version 1.3.1 and ICU plugin version 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... After a couple of hours I found the issue. The configuration was not right and ES was not picking up the analyzer correctly. This did it:

```
{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ducet_sort": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [ "icu_collation" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `settings` bit was unnecessary. I'm not exactly sure why this was happening, but it's nowhere in the docs.